# minion game substrings off-by-one

Tags: python, slice

Overview :

Problem tutorial: [HackerRank minion game practice tutorial](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-minion-game)

```
Input: BAANANAS

Expected output: Kevin 19

My output: Kevin 18
```

As you can see, I'm off-by-one, but I really can't figure out exactly where the error would be.

Here's the code :

```
def minion_game(string):
# your code goes here

vowels = ('A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U')

def kevin(string):
    kevin_list = []
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if string[i] in vowels:
            return len(string) - i
            #Find every possible combination beginning with that letter
            for j in range(len(string)):


                #Gets rid of white-space characters...for some reason....
               if j >= i and string[i:j+1] not in kevin_list:


                    kevin_list.append(string[i:j+1])
    return kevin_list

def stuart(string):
    stuart_list = []
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if string[i] not in vowels:

            #Find every possible combination beginning with that letter
            for j in range(len(string)):

                #Gets rid of white-space characters...for some reason....
                if j >= i and string[i:j+1] not in stuart_list:
                    stuart_list.append(string[i:j+1])
    return stuart_list


def points(words):
    points_list = []

    for substring in words:
        points_list.append(string.count(substring))


    return sum(points_list)



def calculateWinner(player1, score1, player2, score2):
    if score1 > score2:
        return '%s %d' %(player1, score1)
    elif score2 > score1:
        return '%s %d' %(player2, score2)
    else:
        return 'Draw'

#print(kevin(string))
#print("points:", points(kevin(string)))
print(calculateWinner("Stuart", points(stuart(string)), "Kevin", points(kevin(string))))
```

Anything commented out was probably used for debugging (except for the comments themselves)

(Note: the function is called inside `main()`, so it's being called, don't worry. This is just the definition of it)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. It is much simpler and more efficient.

```
def minion_game(string):
    
    stuCount=kevCount=0
    N=len(string)
    
    for i in range(N):
        if string[i] in "AEIOU":  # A vowel letter
                kevCount+=N-i
        else:
                stuCount+=N-i     # A consonant letter
                
    if stuCount > kevCount:
        print("Stuart"+" "+str(stuCount))
    elif kevCount > stuCount:
        print("Kevin"+" "+str(kevCount))
    else:
        print("Draw")
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.
The .count() method in BAANANAS does not count the substring "ANA" twice if it overlaps.
As in the following:
BA[ANA]NAS vs. BAAN[ANA]S
It only counts one of these, not both.